# Is there a way to push my private NuGet packages to GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, devexpress, nuget-package

My web app uses DevExpress.Blazor which is only available as a local NuGet package on my system placed there by the DevExpress installer. There is no public NuGet that has this package.

Pushing it up to GitHub as a private package, so far, appears to require that I spend several hours learning all the details of how to do this (they do not make it easy).

Is there instead a way that all these DLLs in this private NuGet can be pushed up to my project on GitHub and then be available directly when GitHub builds my app? I know that works (without having to do anything) when I publish from Visual Studio to Azure. So I'm hoping there's an equivalent for GitHub.

---

I'm getting closer but still struggling. First off, [here's the DevExpress info on how to add their NuGet package to Azure DevOps](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/400604/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages/integrate-nuget-to-popular-continuous-integration-systems?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T1177340) (unfortunately they do not have instructions for GitHub).

So I've read through [Working with the NuGet registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry) and I believe it has the information I need. But...

It is not clear which approach I should take and I don't have the in depth knowledge to make that determination myself from what is written there.

It also discusses steps without explaining how to accomplish them. For example, if I need to do the following, how do I do it?

> You can publish a package to GitHub Packages by authenticating with a
> nuget.config file, or by using the --api-key command line option with
> your GitHub personal access token (classic).

Any guidance on exactly what to do appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question at a basic level yes, you can push private nuget packages to GitHub. The [Package permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility#about-setting-visibility-and-access-permissions-for-packages) can be tied to repository permissions or set explicitly on each package.

A command line example would be:

```
dotnet nuget push {path} https://nuget.pkg.github.com/{user}/index.json --api-key {key}
```

You should be able to access your nuget package inside of GitHub Actions by virtue of the workflow having package permissions. If you do not have package permissions you can [add it to the workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idpermissions):

```yaml
permissions:
  packages: read
```

Comment: First, thank you. Second, what is {path}? Do I do this once for each of the 7 DevExpress.*.dll files? For {user} is that my GitHub name (DavidThielen in my case)? And for {key} is that a security key I need to create, or something else? TIA

Comment: {path} should be the relative path to your .nupkg file

{user} is your GitHub username OR organization name if you are publishing under an organization.

{key} would be your api key generated with package permissions

more here: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you are consuming the NuGet packages. You talk about needing to learn how to use build pipelines so that calls into question why you need this at all.

The other option is to use their NuGet feed as they describe here:

[Choose Between Offline and Online DevExpress NuGet Feeds](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/116042/nuget/obtain-your-nuget-feed-credentials?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T1177340)

The solution would then be to run:

```
dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.devexpress.com/{your-feed-authorization-key}/api/ --name DevExpress
```

(Replacing `{your-feed-authorization-key}` with the key you get from their support team)

Comment: Actually that link you provided is the info I provided them when I figured out how to do this. Different approach than my question above.